# unsigned integer divison example

Tags: c

I am trying to implement 64bits/64bits unsigned integer division in 32bits machine.

Any 64bits integer type such as long, uint_64, or array, pointers are not allowed to use.

So I have read many many articles including storing, non-storing algorithm to implement this.

But all of them were hard to implement with 32bits, so I finally ran into the below article.

[https://www.cs.utah.edu/~rajeev/cs3810/slides/3810-08.pdf](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Erajeev/cs3810/slides/3810-08.pdf)

Division example which is in page 15 really makes sense, but the one thing I cannot understand is that, why the 2 (0010) represented in `0010 0000`, not `0010` instead.

Since decimal 2 is represented in binary with `0010 0000` instead of `0010` or `0000 0010`,
I am confused how many bits to allocate for the divisor.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: [Have you watched the class videos?](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~rajeev/cs3810/)

Comment: @Cornstalks Wow thanks, I definitely wanted to watch the videos but I couldn't. I'll try thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For the division algorithm there, you first *double* the width of the divisor (so its twice as many bits as the dividend), and then shift the value 'up' into the upper half.  You then shift it down one bit at a time.

So that example is showing a 4-bit division (0b0111 divided by 0b0010).  The first step is then to double the width of the divisor (to 8 bits), shifting it up by 4.  So the divisor in the first step is
 0b0010 0000 (they add the space to make the two 4-bit words clearer).  It will then be shifted down by one bit each step, ending up as 0b0000 0010 (the original divisor) on the last step.

Comment: thanks @Chris Dodd. Do we have to also double the width of the dividend? because decimal 7 is represented with 0000 0111, not only the 0111. Is that only for processing per byte?

Comment: Strictly speaking yes, in order to do the comparisons and subtracts -- but the upper bits will always be zero, so you don't actually need to store them anywhere (don't need flops for them if you are implementing this as a hardware block, just hard-wire them to be 0).

Comment: appreciate for your detailed answer. Can I ask one more thing? I am testing with 9/4, but how many iterations do I have to go through? I thought that we have to go through iterations until divisor reaches least significant bits, but it seems quite not.

Comment: For n-bit divide (where you've expanded to 2n bits), you need exactly n rounds.  The whole point of this is that the shifts and number of rounds is constant, so easy to do in hardware in a fixed amount of time (or hardware if you pipeline it).

Comment: sorry for bothering you again. it seems that divide 7 by 2 requires 5 rounds. what am I missing? appreciate for your help.

Comment: Yes, you're correct for the example shown -- it uses n+1 rounds instead of n, but the first round is not really necessary as the comparison will always be false.  You could instead shift by n-1 bits initially and only do n rounds (which is the way this algorithm is usually described).

Comment: finally I get an idea. thank you. perhaps we need to allocate 128bits to   perform 64bits/64bits division!